# Limiting Netty Connections based on hostname/port and username

Tags: connection, port, limit, netty, hostname

I have a requirement to put a strict limit on the number of connections based on a login name and the hostname/port to which the client is connected.

Any thoughts on approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use ChannelGroup for keeping a track of connections. Based on the contents of the channelGroup, make decisions about limiting connectivity. See the code fragment below. All channels which are added into the channelGroup are automatically removed when closed.

```
class YourHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

ChannelGroup  channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup();

 @Override
public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) 
{
    // make a decision if you want to accept connection
    // if not just close it using ctc.getChannel().close()
}

@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) 
{
    channelGroup.add(ctx.getChannel());
}

}
```

Comment: Having studied the `ChannelGroup` code today I believe I should keep a `Map` of channel group names (based on the username) mapped to channel groups. i.e. `ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChannelGroup>`. In this way I can logically group all of the Channels that are connected for specific usernames. I can then refer to each group by username and find the respective counts. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely reasonable.